# Jenkins API - 403 No valid crumb was included in the request

Tags: jenkins, csrf-token, jenkins-api

I am trying to create credentials via the Rest API using postman.

I send the post request to this domain:

```
http://localhost:8080/credentials/store/system/domain/_/createCredentials
```

I've added a API-Key as authentification, created a crumb via the API (request see below) and added it too.

```py
r = requests.get(f'http://localhost:8080/crumbIssuer/api/json', auth=('admin', 'admin'))
crumb = r.json().get('crumb')
```

Nonetheless, it doesn't work and I get this error page:

```html
<html>

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Error 403 No valid crumb was included in the request</title>
</head>

<body>
    <h2>HTTP ERROR 403 No valid crumb was included in the request</h2>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>URI:</th>
            <td>/credentials/store/system/domain/_/createCredentials</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>STATUS:</th>
            <td>403</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>MESSAGE:</th>
            <td>No valid crumb was included in the request</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>SERVLET:</th>
            <td>Stapler</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <hr><a href="https://eclipse.org/jetty">Powered by Jetty:// 9.4.43.v20210629</a>
    <hr />

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the problem. On the [jenkins website about CSRF Protection](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/security/csrf-protection/) it says:

> The *Default Crumb Issuer* encodes the following information in the
> hash used as crumb:
>
> - The user name that the crumb was generated for
> - The web session ID that the crumb was generated in
> - The IP address of the user that the crumb was generated for
> - A salt unique to this Jenkins instance

I created the crumb via python in a jupyter notebook. The post request on the other hand was made using postman. So the data which was hashed in the crumb didn't match.